# Can a creature with truesight see the invisible sensor created by the Clairvoyance spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, vision-and-light, invisibility

When you cast [*clairvoyance*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/clairvoyance):

> You create an invisible sensor within range in a location familiar to you [...]

If you do this near someone with [truesight](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/adventuring#Truesight), which gives the following benefit:

> A creature with truesight can [...] see invisible creatures and objects

Therefore, if you have truesight, can you see the invisible sensor created by *clairvoyance*?

Comment: Related: [Does detect magic allow detection of scrying?](//rpg.stackexchange.com/q/90084)

Comment: Whatever source you pulled the spell description from does not agree with the official wording. I would recommend using only official sources in the future (or if this is from a translated version, noting that in the question).

Comment: I thought I got it from Roll20, but looking at the text on there it matches your edit.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

## Yes, the sensor can be seen with truesight

I will briefly state what has already been pointed out in [Dinomaster's answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/136761/35259):

The *clairvoyance* spell specifies that it creates "an **invisible sensor**", and truesight it described as allowing a creature to "see **invisible** creatures and **objects**", so this implies that such a sensor can be seen via truesight, although since a sensor isn't explicitly described as an object, it's not conclusive evidence...

In addition to that, a similar situation exists for the spell [*scrying*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/scrying) (PHB, pg. 273), which is made more explicit:

> ... the spell creates an **invisible sensor** within 10 feet of the target. [...] **A creature that can see invisible objects sees the sensor** as a luminous object about the size of your fist.

So not only can creatures with truesight (or any creature that can see invisible objects  for any other reason) see the sensor, but according to *scrying*, it looks like "a luminous objects about the size of your fist".

Given that the language regarding the "invisible sensor" is the same in both spells, it seems as though invisible sensors can be seen by creatures with truesight, and furthermore it's likely that the appearance of the sensor described by *scrying* would be the same for *clairvoyance* as well (or at the very least it gives the DM a precedent to follow).

Comment: In other cases (Wall of Force and the like), the thing created by a spell is not an 'object' for the purposes of object interactions, spells or effects that target objects, etc. What about the sensor that makes it an 'object', since this is a specially defined game term?

Comment: @MarkTO I suppose the fact that Scrying specifically uses the same wording, then clarifies that it is an object that can be seen?

Comment: @MarkTO I'm not saying that a sensor is an object per se, I'm just pointing out that _scrying_ says that creatures that can see invisible objects can also see the sensor. There's also that it's described as a "luminous object", but that's more that it _looks like_ an object, not that it is one. My main point, though, is that _scrying_ sets a precedent for creatures that can see invisible objects being able to see invisible sensors too.

Comment: @NathanS I'm a bit confused though. Wouldn't the fact that they put the wording in *scrying* but not in *clairvoyance* actually imply that they aren't intended to work the same? I'm not sure there is any example of a spell that depends on the wording of another spell without explicitly saying so.

Comment: @Rubiksmoose True; I suppose ultimately _clairvoyance_ doesn't say either way, so we can only infer. _Scrying_ is an example of another spell that includes an "invisible sensor", which does describe how it interacts with being able to see invisible objects, and does so without explicitly labelling the sensor as an object. As you say, that fact the _clairvoyance_ **doesn't** say that could imply that it's only true for _scrying_, or it could be an oversight that they could fix in errata (but haven't, at least not yet). Either way, we're left only with the option of comparing these two spells.

Comment: @rubiksmoose: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/make - *"to produce something, often using a particular substance or material:"* - The wording **"you make"** implies that an object is created.

Comment: @Mindwin object is a game term and thus has a special definition. "You make" certainly implies *something* is created. However, the assumption that anything you "make" via a spell is an object is simply not true. There are many things you can make with spells in game and some of them are clearly not objects. For example you can make creatures, you can make illusions, etc. Even physically created substances such as water are generally not treated as objects by the game's definition.

Comment: @Mindwin as an example of what I mean, look at druidcraft which says: "You create an instantaneous, harmless sensory effect, such as falling leaves, a puff of wind, the sound of a small animal, or the faint odor of skunk." Create, which is the word *clairvoyance* actually uses (not "make"), is here being applied to things that clearly are not objects. They are simply spell effects. The same is true of the sensor as far as the rules tell us.

Comment: I have accepted this answer because I believe it gives the most robust justification even though the rules are potentially unclear.

Answer (score 9):

## Yes

The Claivoyance spell makes an invisible object.

> You create an **invisible sensor** within range in a location familiar to you...

Which can be seen by Truesight

> A creature with truesight can, ... see invisible creatures and **objects**

So yes truesight can see the sensor.

Comment: What makes you think that the sensor is an object? Spells will say when the thing they create is an object and many spell effects are not considered objects (eg wall in wall of force). So how do you justify calling the sensor an object here?

Comment: @rubiksmoose: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/make - *"to produce something, often using a particular substance or material:"* - The wording **"you make"** implies that an object is created.

Comment: @Mindwin object is a game term and thus has a special definition. "You make" certainly implies *something* is created. However, the assumption that anything you "make" via a spell is an object is simply not true. There are many things you can make with  spells in game and some of them are clearly not objects. For example you can make creatures, you can make illusions, etc.